# Loading a flex swf application from jsf page

Tags: flash, apache-flex, jsf, swfobject

I'm working on a JSF application with should embed a Flex swf object on it, however I have not been able to do it successfully . What I'm doing right now is using a Primefaces commandButton which executes a javascript function on the click event:

The code I'm using for it is as follows:

```
<ui:define name="contentPreview">
    <div style="width: 100%;height: 400px;border: 1px solid;">

    <p:commandButton value="Vista Previa Tour" 
                     process="@this"
                     onclick="loadFlexVirtualTour();"
                      style="float:left;"/>


    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="flashContent" rendered="true">
               <p>
            To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
            11.1.0 or greater is installed. 
        </p>

    </h:panelGroup>

    </div>
</ui:define>
```

And the script used to load the swf Object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function loadFlexVirtualTour(){
        alert(UrlExists("virtualTour.swf"))
        // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
        var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";
        // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
        swfobject.embedSWF("virtualTour.swf", "flashContent", "400", "400", swfVersionStr);

        // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
        }

        function UrlExists(url)
        {
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open('HEAD', url, false);
            http.send();
            return http.status!=404;
        }
    </script>
```

UrlExists was a function to check if the resource exists on the given URL, in this case I'm checking for virtualTour.swf to be on the same directory as the jsf page.

The function is executed correctly, since I can see the alert on screen, and even the URLExists function returns true. However the application is not loaded. What I'm doing wrong...

PD: The  tag just generates a  html element, specifically for this case the render html would be

```
 <button id="j_idt43" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="submit" style="float:left;" onclick="loadFlexVirtualTour();;PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'j_idt8',source:'j_idt43',process:'j_idt43'});return false;" name="j_idt43" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

Comment: What I would do first: check swfobject for null/undefined, check HTTP requests with Firebug or similar tool to see if swf is loading, and even review docs on `swfobject` :)